# How to have a counter for retrieving from MYSQL (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

At the moment what i am trying to do is to make an `ArrayList<String>` which contains the room number in my database. So at the moment each row of data has a room number , for eg 1001,1002,1003. So what i need to do is to store those values into the `ArrayList<String>` but the problem is that i don't want duplicates of the same room number inside. So how do i make a `ArrayList<String>` without having duplicates when i run a loop to read all the data in the database.

At the moment this is what i have and i am sure the logic is wrong.

```
ResultSet rs1;
    ArrayList<String> roomNumberList=new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement2 = so.getPreparedStatementWithKey("SELECT room FROM et_elderly ");
        rs1 = statement2.executeQuery();

        while(rs1.next()){
            String num=Integer.toString(rs1.getInt("room"));
            roomNumberList.add(num);
            if(num!=Integer.toString(rs1.getInt("room"))){
                roomNumberList.add(Integer.toString(rs1.getInt("room")));
                num=Integer.toString(rs1.getInt("room"));
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: pick distinct records : `SELECT distinct room FROM et_elderly `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to solve this problem:

1. Change your SQL to select distinct room numbers like:

   ```
    PreparedStatement statement2 = so.getPreparedStatementWithKey("SELECT DISTINCT room FROM et_elderly");
   ```
2. Use Set instead of List like:

   ```
   Set<String> roomNumbers=new HashSet<String>();
   ```

Note Aside, To compare String, don't use `!=` instead use `equals` with negation method.